# Can I use PS/2 barcode scanner with the Compute Module?

Tags: gpio, usb

I'm about to start a project for the Compute Module where I use a barcode scanner but I don't know if it's better to use the [PS/2](https://www.adafruit.com/products/1202) or the [USB](https://www.adafruit.com/products/1203) version.

If I could choose, I would go with PS/2. I what to keep the PIs USB port alone to simplify the access to the flash memory.

I think I'll need a logic level converter. But what protocol should I use? Are drivers already available? Will this be transparent for the applications running on the Pi?

Answer (score 3):

The Raspberry Pi does not support PS/2, so the USB version is probably better.